# Error ==> Cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango110Warning'

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I cloned a django project from github and then I created a virtual env and installed requirements from requirements.txt file and when I load server I get following error:

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/home/kanish/efizza-webapp2/listhome/views.py", line 15, in home
        return render(request, 'index.html')
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 12, in get_template
        engines = _engine_list(using)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 66, in _engine_list
        return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
        return [self[alias] for alias in self]
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
        return [self[alias] for alias in self]
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
        engine = engine_cls(params)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
        options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
        libraries = get_installed_libraries()
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
        for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
      File "/home/kanish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
        "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
    django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load      
'django.templatetags.future': cannot import name  
'RemovedInDjango110Warning'
```

Comment: Likely the `requirements.txt` did not contain the exact version of Django, you probably installed a different version where indeed you can not import this anymore.

Comment: so now what to do basically ? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: django/templatetags/future.py was removed in 1.10. You seem to have files from multiple versions of Django. Try uninstalling Django and removing the django/ folder, and then reinstalling 1.10.

Comment: you can see :
https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox/issues/497 
https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/706