# I don't know how to resolve this error 'RemovedInDjango110Warning'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

when I created the project. And run the server I got the error

django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'django.templatetags.future': cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango110Warning'

Comment: What version of Django and Python did you use to create the project? Looks like you may have a very old and unsupported version of Django

Comment: Please check comments there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892417/error-cannot-import-name-removedindjango110warning
simply uninstall django then reinstall it. It should work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.